Upgraded numpy and now I am overwhelmed by RuntimeWarning
Just upgraded numpy to the latest intel conda's, I am at pandas 2.2.1, numpy 1.24.3 and numexpr 2.10.0
If I try something simple like
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
df["A"] = [1, 2, np.NaN, 3]
print(df)

then I get five run time warnings.
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  has_small_values = ((abs_vals < 10 ** (-self.digits)) & (abs_vals > 0)).any()  
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  has_small_values = ((abs_vals < 10 ** (-self.digits)) & (abs_vals > 0)).any() 
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  has_large_values = (abs_vals > 1e6).any()  
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  has_small_values = ((abs_vals < 10 ** (-self.digits)) & (abs_vals > 0)).any()  
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  has_small_values = ((abs_vals < 10 ** (-self.digits)) & (abs_vals > 0)).any()

For a more complicated code the result is just overwhelming, hundreds and hundreds of such messages.
Did numpy drop support for NaN ??
EDIT
Building on some helpful comments, I can make a minimal reproducible example:
conda update conda
conda create -n "test_numpy" python=3.10
conda activate test_numpy
conda install -c intel numpy==1.24.3 pandas=2.2.1

At that point df["A"] = [0., 1., np.NaN, 2.] will cause run-time errors because of some internal comparisons being made with the "<" and ">" operators and np.NaN deep in the heart of the core routines, like "Expressions.py"
[I should also note that the bug was fixed by 1.24.6, so the fix was to simply upgrade....]

Have you restarted your interpreter/notebook after upgrading?

Deactivated and re-activated conda environment:: Yes

I'm on my phone now but curious. Do you still get a df out of it?

(Separately, the reason I did a quick edit of your title because you really shouldn't conflate warnings with errors. Unhandled errors will stop the program. This has kept going)

Yes, @roganjosh. Everything was fine. Except for the run-time warnings, which I traced to "line 73" of "Expressions.py" somewhere in the core of numpy and which was far deeper into op codes than the limit of my curiosity. The warnings have disappeared with 1.26.4

@Tunneller but questions on SO are not just for you ;) There might be an interesting issue, so give people time before you close it

I tested with those exact versions and can't reproduce the issue

I dropped requirement for intel channel which let me upgrade to numpy==1.26.4 and the glitch has now gone. This with numexpr=2.10.0 and pandas=2.2.1.

I don't think you should close the question. If that is the issue then write it up as best you can. It's early-days and people might understand the issue better to help other people in the future

IMO this behavior was not reproducible, unless you can provide code to reproduce it (which isn't the case in my hands with the versions you cited) then I'd delete the question

@mozway fair enough if you've had chance to repro. I didn't have a chance to try

So to condense that repro, conda install -c intel numpy==1.24.3 pandas=2.2.1, is that right? You can install multiple packages at the same time, in fact it saves running the solver each time. Please move that into the question. The idea is the question should cover the problem and answers should covers solutions.

Hi @wjandrea, I just tried your proposal and it didnt work and seems to be raising a separate question: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service

@Tunneller Oh OK, well my main point was that the details about how to reproduce the issue should be in the question, not an answer. I just thought I could kill two birds with one stone :p

These packages are such a moving target. The "terse" version failed if python was v11. But it is fine if python is V10. So now I can condense the repro. I will add to the original question.
